# Why does the sentence use "doing this" instead of "doing it"

Tags: grammaticality, reference, it-this

I have two sentences that I was unsure if I needed to use "doing it" or "doing this". Now I know that the correct one is the one with "doing this" but I don't understand the reason why. The two sentences are as follows:

> *Before you download any music from the site, make sure you understand the legal implications of doing **it**.*

> *Before you download any music from the site, make sure you understand the legal implications of doing **this**.*

I think that "this" in the second sentence refers to the phrase "you understand the legal implications". So, that's why the second sentence is correct. And if not, can anyone please explain?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  Why do you think *it* is not correct?  The difference sounds like a preference of style; don't both sentences work without being incorrect?

Comment: 'So' also works fine. All, according to pragmatics, have the same prior referent (the downloading of any music from the site),

Comment: "Doing it" is something you do in the back seat with that cutie you met at the concert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ***it*** and ***this*** refer back to

> you download any music from the site

and not to the phrase "you understand the legal implications" as you say.

The difference between the two sentences is fine, but your intuition is right, ***this*** does a more successful job than ***it***, though the latter would not be grammatically incorrect.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/it-this-and-that-in-paragraphs) explains:

> We use ***it*** *to continue to refer to the topic we are already writing or speaking about*:
>
> - The heart is the central organ in our bodies. ***It*** is used to pump oxygen around the body through the bloodstream. (*It* refers back to *The heart*)

So in a way, *it* is meant not to draw too much attention to itself, but just ensures the flow of the sentence, the continuity of information on the subject. About ***this***, Cambridge says:

> We can use ***this*** to refer back to whole clauses and sentences and to previous parts of a text. ***This*** *highlights the information referred to much more strongly than **it***. Writers often use *this* when a point or idea is to become an important part of the discussion that follows:
>
> - More and more people are discovering that Tai Chi is one of the most valuable forms of exercise. ***This*** has led to a big demand for classes. (*This* refers back to a whole sentence.)

Do not forget that ***this*** is a [***demonstrative** pronoun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrative) so it is ***deictic***: it ***indicates***, ***points out*** and ***identifies***.

So rather than considering one or the other correct, I think it is a matter of matching the ***intention*** of your statement. Do you want to simply to avoid repetition and pass on to the next piece of information about the subject? Use *it*. Do you want to make the reader stop and focus on the particular action of *do*? Use *this*.